# Append SESID as GET value to every URL on page in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, cookies

Is there any simple way to APPEND SESSID=value to every URL in rendered page?

**WHY?**
I want to handle session even the users browser has cookie disabled. I have lot of code, so Im looking for some "clever" solution not just manualy rewrite all links.

Note that I do NOT use native PHP session management with session start like that:

```
session_start();
```

and Im running on ZendFramework if there is some tools.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: You do not want to do this. session IDs in URLS is a huge security hole. Basic scenario: someone likes a page on your site, cuts/pastes the URL into facebook, and boom, everyone of his viewers on facebook is now using that person's session. DO NOT DO THIS.

Comment: i am having same problem . did u get solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try `ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);` before `session_start();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable transient session IDs.

```
; trans sid support is disabled by default.
; Use of trans sid may risk your users security.
; Use this option with caution.
; - User may send URL contains active session ID
;   to other person via. email/irc/etc.
; - URL that contains active session ID may be stored
;   in publically accessible computer.
; - User may access your site with the same session ID
;   always using URL stored in browser's history or bookmarks.
; http://php.net/session.use-trans-sid
session.use_trans_sid = 0
```